# Apex Error (Image to PDF conversion) : BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string

Tags: utf-8, salesforce, blob, attachment, apex

So i have this task where i have to convert the image uploaded in Notes and Attachment object to PDF. For that i created a trigger(before insert) on Attachment object and used the below mentioned code,

I used the standard EncodingUtil to convert the image Body in the proper format,

I tried this code

```
    attachmentObj.Body = blob.toPdf(attachmentObj.Body.toString());
```

But i get the error message "BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string",

So after some research i also used tried this,

```
    String encodeStringBody = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(attachmentObj.Body);

    attachmentObj.Body = blob.toPdf(encodeStringBody);
```

But the attachment created have ineligible body. I cannot see anything when i 'view file' in the attachment object.

I expect the file to be converted to PDF but both the code i used have problems.

Please help me with this if anyone find solution to the problem.

Comment: Take this question to salesforce.stackexchange.com you'll get more experienced eyes on it